# Bypass IBM Worklight server to access web service

Tags: jquery-mobile, extjs, ibm-mobilefirst

I have a question regarding IBM Worklight. We are evaluating few cross platform frameworks. One of the tools which we are evaluating is IBM Worklight. Our question is, to access a web service from IBM worklight, we can do it by using adapters. If we are using the adapter, then, we need to host the adapters in the IBM Worklight server component. Is there any way access a web service from IBM Worklight without using the adapter. For example, to develop UI in IBM worklight, I can use, Sencha, JQuery Mobile or Dojo Mobile. Can I access the web services from the above libraries (Sencha, JQuery Mobile or Dojo Mobile) without using the IBM Worklight Server? I know that if I bypass the server, then I cannot get the features of IBM Worklight server like, caching, filteting etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the ajax call.

```
WLJQ.ajax( "http://example.com" )
.done(function (data) {
console.log(data);
});
```

You can use jQuery or $ by : var $ = WLJQ; or var jQuery = WLJQ;. WLJQ is worklight jquery that is been provided by IBM worklight.

Make sure why you don't want the adapter functionality and worklight server functionality before going for this approach.

Comment: Thanks Rajesh. We already have a web server and all server setup. We dont need to install IBM worklight server. That is the reason that I am asking. It is not recommended by IBM? Can you plz tell me what are the benefits for using IBM WOrklight server?

Comment: If you intend on using ANYTHING Worklight-related: direct update, remote disable, push notifications, authentication, application authenticity, location services, etc, you will need Worklight Server and adapters as well. This is covered in my answer below as well as in the follow-up answers in the links I've provided. Some of these, even if not requiring adapters, will require server connectivity and access to the Worklight database.

Comment: Use $ instead of WLJQ. WLJQ is internal reference and it might change without any notice.

Answer (score 1):

Of course, you can use AJAX to send requests, etc to the various web services. But as you mentioned if Worklight authentication and access to Worklight features is needed, adapters are still required.

If you intend on using ANYTHING Worklight-related: direct update, remote disable, push notifications, authentication, application authenticity, location services, etc, you will need Worklight Server and adapters as well. This is also covered in the follow-up answers in the links below. Some of these, even if not requiring adapters, will require server connectivity and access to the Worklight database.

Related questions:

- [Worklight http adapter questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15098203/worklight-http-adapter-questions)
- [IBM Worklight - Can commercial apps be created using the Developer Edition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17886155/ibm-worklight-can-commercial-apps-be-created-using-the-developer-edition)
- [How can i call adapter from another worklight project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21090474/how-can-i-call-adapter-from-another-worklight-project)
- [Why do worklight apps need a Worklight Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15191841/why-do-worklight-apps-need-a-worklight-server)